# How to avoid repeating generic type constraints with every usage in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

How do you avoid repeating types constantly when using generics in Typescript? If I have some constraint on a generic type then I must repeat that constraint anywhere I use the generic type. This is tedious and not very DRY.

```
//A constraint on this generic
type MyConstraint = { bar: number }
type GenericOne<T extends MyConstraint> = {
    foo: T
}
```

To create an instance I annoyingly have to repeat the constraint because TS only does generic inference on functions

```
//This annoyance would I think be solved by generic values https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574
const testok: GenericOne<MyConstraint> = { foo: { bar: 1 } }
```

Now if I want to use my generic type in other places I also have to repeat the constraint!

```
const makeGenericOne2: <T extends MyConstraint>(arg: GenericOne<T>) => GenericOne<T> = (arg) => {
    return arg
}
```

At least now I can create from object literals without repeating myself

```
const test5 = makeGenericOne2({ foo: { bar: 1 } })
// And I get nice error messsages
const test6 = makeGenericOne2({foo: {baz: 1}})
```

The only way to avoid repeating the constraint seems to be a conditional type with inference

```
const makeGenericOne: <T>(arg: T extends GenericOne<infer U> ? T : never) => T = (arg) => {
    return arg
}
```

I can still create instances from object literal without repeating myself

```
const test3 = makeGenericOne({ foo: { bar: 1 } })
```

But now the error messages aren't so nice.

```
//"number not assignable to never" instead of { baz: 1 } is missing property "bar: number"
const test4 = makeGenericOne({ foo: { baz: 1 } })
```

It seems like the following is needed -- infer T because we know it must extend Myconstraint

```
const propagateGeneric: <infer T>(arg: GenericOne<T>) => GenericOne<T>
```

Unfortunately this isn't allowed in TS at the moment.

How do I "propogate" the constraint on a generic type to avoid repeating it everywhere that generic type is used?

[Sandbox Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=38&ssc=71&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTCCAIGMHsDsGcAuAnAhgS1o8dyIBbrzgDmAprGcupALABQiAngA5ngCyTAwnEmpmwBecAG9wAI1TIAXOFgBXALYSq4AL4NmbcAHEKVGgHlKAHgAq4MgA9EFACbEuvBCgxYAfOBGiG4f%20AAZtDQcuYMmvQMIObQUMhkqHbgqOAANuh2aGngAJIpsLDQTJgkaUzg%20KgAbuyIcQlsSXj47DCuAliSZJCoCvDs5gDKOLDl4PbQZMTklNSQ4JiBVBSQ7LiBCrCQiOh80cDmhMSohcWna%20AA7tAKafZ5LZgA1t3g8NBptQ8SFbOGC2qqDSCmmlUQiBY8BkIBImXwCgkADoYEpgEoaMhoB9AohDqwyENINQWHiiPBQfBgABGADsAFZaQAWBjtJB4ab1Z5yfRzYxmZx8NyCLw%20IIhOTiKSycDUjQaBgHABy0Cui0Cjyup2w9XA-XYSj%20BnmeAJi1gOAIahYaVQa2I%20WBH0qNTqDTITR1rSgQs6iAAhKyheAlKhnmReQCTGQAExyCxWWwOJw8X3uRAeAAU0hIPON-LIFg8AEpvF5I-No0XvOBs8gSKWhF5fPQAuAEogFMgLTmIor6CBQNg0ol2UU1flehbiYlkoEsUocBIAFY9YeZKhO67w27YRqz0ohpgDNKBIOuDlIek10PhisFmOZ8TBUJiSTSORy9QaYsHcCgWAHnychsFgGh2CoLFkBDaZ4HgVByHgc92TsJAADYbzDCN80gaNH1EF9JSkAAvT91HUX8oiomJvTgcYtQqXUamgdAHn3JJDytH0OnTd4yDIJRiF1VQUm4%20xMj2WBgVNHQrnhc1lgSbYyGQ7Bb2wvlcMoeNzCzHMwkTOxAOIe8tMLJY1AAVS8AB%20cBLDkShamQRsvEsEQ6wbMsxD8AIOy7Ht6z7ajgEnU53l2NIchnJJ2EwJALjBedoEXaAVzXdIN2ybcCF3dsPQPWASCPE8z3oNkdU5ABmTC7xw6Mn3FV8pQ-WV5Qo-sQAAIQUUDVRaCDkCgmC4IQsFpAoABybBnTAtYkXAA4ACJFBUNQimwVA4PQEgpIkEc8DiJyqCW80kESB5oA1FrSLa78iBDclDxYLE2GQZhwCW6VHOUVRkCW1TL0QJlao0qNKEawi3xIz92so-sDgACX6yZHiWl7oBYaASFi06uIqv1RlE-4TW0N0UmqFi2IKjiisWbAyGcpgrlaBIWmaEmaBkuLiH1ewbIOXIZv4wTMvDAbxSi1VDweygyHseXwAAWiVhS1EsVRen1a52Gecd6ZDfoGaTQDOCYAn00BjGWAQ2LTPjCzoN0zy800qtdNcvR6rMXSgA)

Comment: What is the function `makeGenericOne` trying to do, exactly? I'm probably missing something, but it isn't too clear from the question

Comment: If you leave out `extends MyConstraint` from the first function, you do at least get a helpful error `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyConstraint'.` So even though you repeat yourself there, it wont compile if it doesn't match, so it's all kept type safe in case you refactor and forget to change it in both places. So, in practice, it's not really a problem, even in a large codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky but it seems to work

```
//A constraint on this generic
type MyConstraint = { bar: number }
type GenericOne<T extends MyConstraint = MyConstraint> = {
    foo: T
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it works to provide a default? Won't that delete some type information if a generic function accepts a type param extending GenericOne?

Comment: As I understand you have 2 problems here. 1. You don't want to repeat the extended type in GenericOne and solution is default types. 2. You don't want to extend from MyConstraint if you are going to pass a type and I think we can avoid this restriction anyway I don't know how. Won't that delete some type information? Probably no, because T still extends MyConstraint